# Loading information from file in different ways

Tags: java, class, file-io, methods

My program currently has this working:

```
        Bank bank = new Bank();

        bank.openAccount(new CheckingAccount(10100, new Customer("First", "Last"),500.00,false));
        bank.openAccount(new CheckingAccount(10101, new Customer("First", "Last"),2000.00,true));
        bank.openAccount(new SavingsAccount(2010, new Customer("First", "Last"),5000.00,0.02));
```

Now I am trying to load this information from a file instead, but I ran into a bit of a wall. I want the new Customer information to include both the first and last name which are stored in separate index positions as separate variables, but while this will work:

```
        new Customer[FIRST_INDEX],
```

I can't seem to get it to accept two index positions without creating a new Customer again. This is turn is causing issue with the method in Accounts where I'd like to keep the same format. How can I go about doing this?

```
    public CheckingAccount(int accountNumber, Customer owner, double currentBalance, boolean freeChecks) 
{
    super(accountNumber, owner, currentBalance);
    this.freeChecks = freeChecks;
}
```

Another problem I am running into is that the last index position can be one of two variables depending on if I am dealing with a checking account or a savings account:

```
private final static int FREE_CHECKS_INDEX = 4; // This loads a boolean
private final static int INTEREST_INDEX = 4;    // This loads a double
```

Given this, I'm not entirely sure if my above approach would even work at all. The program is supposed to load either a Checking Account or Savings Account object, but since both types of accounts are stored in the same file I am wondering if I could read the last index position of each line of the text file before creating the object, but I'm not really sure how to go about doing that.

To be clear, I have this problem working perfectly without loading the data from the file, I am just unsure about the best approach for adapting it without having to rewrite all my other classes. Here's the new thing I am trying to do which I know isn't right:

```
    protected static void loadAccountInformationFromFile() throws Exception 
    {
        try ( Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_CUSTOMER_FILE)) ) 
            {
                String record;
                String[] fields;


                while ( fin.hasNext() ) 
                    {
                        record = fin.nextLine();

                        fields = record.split(",");

                        Bank bank = new Bank();

                        bank.openAccount
                            (
                                new CheckingAccount(Integer.parseInt(accountNumber[ACCOUNT_NUMBER_INDEX]), 
                                new Customer[FIRST_INDEX, LAST_INDEX], 
                                currentBalance[BALANCE_INDEX], 
                                freeChecks[FREE_CHECKS_INDEX]
                                )
                            );
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    throw e;    
                } // end try
        }
```

Comment: Just a tip, two newer ways to read lines from a file, which look way cleaner: `String[] lines = new String(Files.readAsBytes(Paths.get(FILE_PATH))).split("\n");` or `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH)).lines().forEach(line -> { });`

Comment: Something like that could work. Store it into an array, and then use the array to create variables that then create the objects.